# C# MetaData API ValueSetValuesDefinition CS0029Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Tags: c#, salesforce, metadata

I am trying to write a C# program to insert Picklist Values into Salesforce. I am getting an error though for this line. Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MetadataService.CustomValue>' to 'MetadataService.CustomValue[]'

How can I correct this?

```
valueDefinition.value = values;
```

I was referencing the below link.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/186764/create-picklist-using-metadata-api

```
 public void InsertPickListValues()
    {
        try { 
        MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
        customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
        customField.fullName = "ACustomObjectInDotNet6__c.TPicklist__c";
        customField.label = "TPicklist";
    
        customField.description = "";

        //Create the valueSet for picklist type
        MetadataService.ValueSet picklistValueSet = new MetadataService.ValueSet();

        //For each ValueSet, we have either ValueSetValuesDefinition or ValueSettings and some other attributes
        MetadataService.ValueSetValuesDefinition valueDefinition = new MetadataService.ValueSetValuesDefinition();

     //   List<MetadataService.CustomValue> Customvalues = new List<MetadataService.CustomValue>();
        List<MetadataService.CustomValue> values = new List<MetadataService.CustomValue>();

        MetadataService.CustomValue customValue1 = new MetadataService.CustomValue();
        customValue1.fullName = "TPicklist__c"; //API name of picklist value
        customValue1.@default = true;
        customValue1.description = "false";
        customValue1.isActive = true;
        customValue1.label = "new";

        values.Add(customValue1);

        valueDefinition.value = values;
        valueDefinition.sorted = false;
        
        picklistValueSet.valueSetDefinition = valueDefinition;

        customField.valueSet = picklistValueSet;

        MetadataService.SaveResult[] update = ms.updateMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customField });
        
        foreach (MetadataService.SaveResult l in update)
        {
            if (l.success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed" + l.errors[0].message);
            }

        }

    }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unexpected error: " + e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
```

}

Comment: A `List<T>` is not an `Array<T>`. Perhaps you should read a C# tutorial first? You don't even need a `List<T>` for the code posted

Comment: Try `valueDefinition.value = values.ToArray();`